# Reading Tagged Values on a Package using the Automation Interface

Tags: java, enterprise-architect

The Java automation interface to EA does not appear to provide a method to access Tagged Values on Package objects.  In my model, however, I have placed some tagged values in my package object.

Any ideas as to how I might be able to read this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is accomplished by accessing the package's Element and then reading the tagged values from that.

```
Element pkgElement = pkg.GetElement();
Collection<TaggedValue> taggedValues = pkgElement.GetTaggedValues();
```

The collection of tagged values can then be processed to read the desired data.